# Conversion between SQL Real and .NET double

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I have a column in a T-SQL database that consists of real values, but when I convert it to double I get something different than what was stored.

For example, I pick one row which has **1.15** stored. When I convert it with:

```
Convert.ToDouble(reader["VAT"]);
```

I get:

```
1,14999997615814
```

Why? And how do I convert a real to double and recieve the same value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-net

Comment: What's the type of your column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the data type of your column from `real` to `float`. If you visit this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx), you will notice that `float` SQL Server data type maps to `Double`, `Nullable<Double>` CLR types. On the other hand, `real` SQL Server data type maps to `Single`, `Nullable<Single>`
CLR types. I suspect that's your problem.